# how to make correct guess riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a riccati equation which I have been trying to work out shown below.

$(x-1)\frac {dy}{dx}-x(4x+5)+4(2x+1)y-4y^2=0$

find the particular solution $y_1$, and the general solution using $y=y_1+\frac1u$.
In previous equations usually the $y_1$ is given but here it is not. I know im meant to make a guess and work it out until I get an answer, but do I just make any random guess or is there a better way to make an educated guess? also how do I eve know if the guess is right ?

Some help in how to solve it would also be appreciated

Comment: This is referred to by finding solutions by quadrature. Check out the wiki page for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Obtaining_solutions_by_quadrature

Answer (score 2):

Hint: I look at the coefficients/functions involved and then try to guess something with the form of the coefficients/functions involved. Only polynomials involved in this problem, so lets try a first guess with $y_1 = ax+b$ (we try first order because second order would force the coefficient of $x^2$ to be zero because of $-4y^2$) and see if you can find meaningful values for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: i was able to get $y_1=x+1/2$ so it seems to have worked, but im still not completely sure about how to choose a good guess. also is there any way to know wether that answer i got is right or not ?

Comment: I would use wolfram alpha (online) to check if it is a solution is really a particular solution.